# Differences in Response Data Type Between Local and Production Laravel Project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, mariadb

I'm encountering a puzzling issue with a Laravel project running on my local XAMPP server and a production server. The local server is using PHP 8.2.4 with Apache 2.4.56, while the production server is using PHP 8.2.9 with Apache 2.4.57. Both servers have identical Laravel project files.

In my Laravel project, I have a simple route like this:

```php
Route::get('users', function () {
    return \App\Models\User::all();
});
```

On my local server, when I access this route, I get a JSON response like this:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test user",
        "test_integer": 505,
        "email": "sdsdsds",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    }
]
```

However, on the production server, the response looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test user",
        "test_integer": "555",
        "email": "sdsdfdfdfsdsds",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    }
]
```

The difference is in the data type of the `test_integer` field. On the local server, it's an integer (`505`), while on the production server, it's a string (`"555"`).

Here's some additional information about the PHP PDO modules:

###### Local Development Server (PHP 8.2.4)

- PDO support => enabled
- PDO drivers => mysql, pgsql, sqlite

###### pdo_mysql:

- PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
- Client API version => mysqlnd 8.2.4

###### Production Server (PHP 8.2.9)

- PDO support => enabled
- PDO drivers => mysql, odbc, pgsql, sqlite

###### pdo_mysql

- PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
- Client API version => 3.3.6

I've confirmed that both servers have the same Laravel project files, and the code for this route is identical. Both servers also have PHP modules such as `mysqli` and `mysqlnd`.

What could be causing this difference in data type between the two servers, especially in the context of PDO and the PHP versions, and how can I ensure consistent behavior?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do both databases  have the same column type for that field in the SQL table?

Comment: Is there a huge difference in MySQL versions? The client Client API version seems to indicate this. You could cast the specific columns to either an integer or string in your model, that would probably make the behavior more or less the same.

Comment: @ADyson yes both have exact the same database and laravel files (copy+paste)

Comment: @Sitethief I am suspecting with the driver mysqlnd causing the issue, i am will create a new server without installing mysqlnd , and will see if i get the same issue with current production server

Comment: @Sitethief that is a good patch, but a total horrible idea to implement on a production server, because you are having an unexpected behaviour (if the test do not catch this because it is not reproducible, somehow) you will have to go over each field casting it when you should not, totally horrendous engineering idea

Comment: @Q8root based on how Laravel works, you have either a cast somewhere changing that value type, something cached (I do not think this is the issue), or the database is not right. There could be a bug on your laravel version, but I honestly doubt it. Try this, take a screenshot or paste the result of asking the database what fields it has (and field types). Then try running `php artisan tinker` and get that user like `User::find(1);` and see if it is still being casted as `string` instead of `int`. This are debugging steps, let me know when you have an update

Comment: @Sitethief my issue that i received an app source code from some development company, and that development company running the current backend in server where i get a response string for integers, and their app code is relay to get a string values from the backend, if i switch the backend server where it will return integers as integer i will get a lot of errors in mobile app

Comment: @Q8root you never stated which one is correct, should it be `int` or `string`?

Comment: @Q8root one more basic thing you can do is set up a docker image (use docker compose) and use exactly those versions and see what happens. For me, the PDO extension and `mysqlixxxxxx` has nothing to do with your issue. It may be a PHP config thing too

Comment: @matiaslauriti the int is correct, i will try to apply using the docker image

Answer (score 0):

I solved it once when I used `nd_pdo_mysql` instead.

(If you are using CPanels they're activating `nd_pdo_mysql` automatically when you enable the `php8-mysqlnd`)